# Criterion for Set of Linearly Independent Functions has a dense span

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis, continuity

This post is related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1559947/linear-independence-and-schauder-basis).  Let $C(\mathbb{R})$ be the space of continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ with the compact-open topology and $\{f_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ be a set of linearly independent functions.  Is there a simple (but non-tautological) criterion for $\operatorname{span}(\{f_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty})$ dense in $C(\mathbb{R})$?

**Note:**  I do not want to assume that the sequence I'm interested in forms a subalgebra of $C(\mathbb{R})$; but I can assume that it separates points and it is non-where vanishing.

Comment: You should definitely check out the [Stone-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem,_real_version). Not 100% sure it applies to your situation, but if you've never seen it before it provides an interesting angle to start thinking about your question.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC  Thanks.  Actually I did but I'm not sure it applies at face value.  But maybe I can figure something about it out.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm not diving in to the details (which is why this is a comment and not an answer), but does the version titled "Locally compact version" not apply to your question?

Comment: It does but I don't want to assume $\{f_i\}$ is closed under multiplication.

Comment: D'oh, I knew I'd missed something.